# reverse coding with dplyr in R

Tags: r

I am trying to reverse code a variable in my dataset. The variable column has numbers and these are: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7. In sum, I want 1 to be 6, 2 to be 5, 3 to be 4 etc. Yet, I also want to exclude number '7' because it is the code for people who did not answer the question in the survey.
I tried mutate in dplyr package. It did good to some extent. I used it like that *mutate(KS_data, Rev35 = abs(Question_35 - 7))*. But, I could not exclude number 7.
What are the possible ways? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr::recode` you can reverse the coding of your variable like so:

```r
set.seed(42)

x <- sample(1:7, 20, replace = TRUE)

rec_x <- setNames(c(6:1, NA), 1:7)

library(dplyr)

data.frame(x = x) %>% 
  mutate(x1 = recode(x, !!!rec_x))
#>    x x1
#> 1  1  6
#> 2  5  2
#> 3  1  6
#> 4  1  6
#> 5  2  5
#> 6  4  3
#> 7  2  5
#> 8  2  5
#> 9  1  6
#> 10 7 NA
#> 11 7 NA
#> 12 4  3
#> 13 1  6
#> 14 5  2
#> 15 6  1
#> 16 4  3
#> 17 2  5
#> 18 2  5
#> 19 7 NA
#> 20 3  4
```

Comment: thank you. that's what I need. but actually I am just a beginner in R, so, can you please explain what the words ''set.seed, x, rec_x, setNames and data.frame'' mean for me? by this way, I will be able to use this coding for my dataset.

Comment: Hi Milan. `set.seed` is for reproducibility. It sets the seed for drawing random numbers via `sample`. By using `set.seed` I make sure that I and you always get the same numbers when running the code. `rec_x` defines the recoding. This is a named vector where the names are the original values 1:7 and the values are the new values by which I want to replace the old values. Finally `data.frame` is a way to manually make a data.frame. Here I simply make a data frame with name x (LHS) and the random example numbers x on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can use `rev` on the `lag` of the column

```
library(dplyr)
KS_data <- KS_data %>%
      mutate(Rev35  = rev(lag(Question_35)))
```

-output

```
#  Question_35 Rev35
#1           1     6
#2           2     5
#3           3     4
#4           4     3
#5           5     2
#6           6     1
#7           7    NA
```

---

Or another option is to subtract from the `max` value and replace the element that is 0 to `NA`

```
KS_data <- KS_data %>% 
   mutate(Rev35 = na_if(max(Question_35)  - Question_35, 0))
#  Question_35 Rev35
#1           1     6
#2           2     5
#3           3     4
#4           4     3
#5           5     2
#6           6     1
#7           7    NA
```

#### data

```
KS_data <- data.frame(Question_35 = 1:7)
```

Comment: sorry, I used the exact copy of the code you sent but it did not work. Is there a problem with me?

Comment: @MilanWoland if you can show a reprodcuible example and the exact issue, it would help

Comment: @MilanWoland Do you have a `numeric` column or `character`

Comment: they're numeric. the output should be like the output you posted above. but, I do not know how to see the output of the function you sent. what should I do to see the output? then I can share a picture of it if it is not correct. and sorry, I am just a beginner in R.

Comment: @MilanWoland I am guessing that you need assignment i.e. `KS_data <- KS_data %>% 
       mutate(Rev35 = na_if(max(Question_35)  - Question_35, 0))` so that new columns gets updated in the original object and then you can check `KS_data`

Comment: well, fyi, 'KS_data' is the name of the excel file that I imported in R which contains all the questions used in the survey. 'Question_35' is my column that I want to mutate. So, should I still use this ''KS_data <- KS_data %>% mutate(Rev35 = na_if(max(Question_35) - Question_35, 0))'' ?

Comment: @MilanWoland Yes, that would create the column 'Rev35' in the `KS_data` object.  then you can check the full data with `View` (in Rstudio) or just extract the coumn i..e `KS_data$Rev35`

Comment: oh, thank you sooo much. this code made a great job for me. it created a new column named Rev35 like I wanted to.